# Apache Ignite static IP won't connect

Tags: ignite

Client Configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>

        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <!-- Override local port. -->
                <property name="localPort" value="8081"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>localhost:8080</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Server Configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="8080"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="shared" value="false" />
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>localhost:8080</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I start up my server, no error messages.  I start up my client and it hangs saying:

> [17:31:35] Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry
>   to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure
>   the frequency of retries): [localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]

Sad.

It seems to work with multicast, but that's no an option for us.  Both server and client are running on the same node in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DiscoverySpi` and `CommunicationSpi` are different components used for different purposes, and they are using different TCP connections. Therefore, if you want to use 8080 for discovery, you should set `localPort` property on `DiscoverySpi` while you're doing this for `CommunicationSpi`.